# PHP email sent successfully but not received by Gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, xampp

I have some code that has worked for me in the past, but isn't anymore, for some reason I don't understand.  I'm pretty sure the problem isn't in the code itself, since 1) I haven't changed anything, and 2) it's worked for me in the past.  I am using XAMPP and PHP.

My webpage allows a user to fill out a contact form and send an email through PHP.  It seems to execute successfully, since it takes the user to "thankyou.html" as a result.  To troubleshoot the issue, I have 1) cleared my browser's cache and 2) checked my spam folder in Gmail.

But I still can't find my email, and don't know why.  I'm not familiar with how SMTP works; if the problem has to do with that, then I would appreciate an explanation.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$field_first_name = $_POST['cf_first_name'];
$field_last_name = $_POST['cf_last_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
$field_reference = $_POST['cf_reference'];

$mail_to = 'myself@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a website visitor '.$field_first_name.' '.$field_last_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_first_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message."\n";
$body_message .= 'Reference: '.$field_reference;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                //alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
                window.location = 'thankyou.html';
        </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to someemail@gmail.com');
                window.location = 'home.php';
        </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked originator email inbox for bounced email?

Comment: You have to check the server logs for mail my be due to lot of spam emails account is temporarily  blocked

Comment: @ J A, I checked the originator email inbox, I don't see any bounced emails.  @dianuj:  I'm new at this...how would I check server logs?  Also, I tried sending/receiving to/from two new email addresses so as to avoid a temporary blockage of my account, but I am still not receiving any emails...

Comment: Are you sending from your local machine, or a server on the internet? How is PHP configured to send mail? Are you using a local SMTP server to forward mail, or is mail() sending it directly (this is configured in php.ini I think)?

Comment: By the way, you should filter `$field_email` prior to using it, as presently your script can act as a spam relay. Consider what happens if the user sends `a@example.com\r\nTo: spamvictim@hotmail.com` for this value.

Comment: Did you use XAMPP when it worked as well?

Comment: @halfer, I am sending from my local machine. I am using whatever default settings for PHP that came with XAMPP.  How do I check if I'm using a local SNMP server?  How can I filter $field_email?  I am pretty new to this.

Comment: @Wikunia, yes, I was using XAMPP when it was working as well.

Answer (score 0):

At least AOL automatically drops **all** emails sent by PHP's internal `mail` (I don't know how they detect it, it simply will not show up in the inbox).

A solution is to use a email library like `PHPMailer` and send your emails via a real SMTP server.

*Edit:* Does your local machine have a dynamic or fixed IP address? Almost every serious SMTP server does reject emails sent by dynamic IP addresses.

Comment: Like I mentioned before, I was able to send emails to my Gmail account (although they appeared in my Spam folder) before without a problem.  I would rather avoid using unnecessary email libraries...

Answer (score 0):

I am using this: (in my website and not in XAMPP)

```
$from = "mail@mail.de";
$to = "mail@mail.de";
$subject = "subject";
$mailtext = "blablabla";
mail($to, $subject, $mailtext, "From: $from ");
```

And it's working!

But I tried it with XAMPP as well and nothing happens :(
So I don't know how to use mail() with XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

As of Nov 2022
Anyone sending emails to Gmail accounts, including personal accounts ending in @gmail.com or googlemail.com, and Google Workspace accounts for work or school must set up either SPF or DKIM to avoid Gmail blocking or marking your emails as spam.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786

Comment: You can use SMTP to avoid the emails are getting into spam or blocked by receivers. https://jnavane.blogspot.com/2022/10/why-we-need-smtp-on-top-of-php-mail.html